# strings.xml on MVPand clean architecture

Tags: android, architecture, mvp, clean-architecture

I'm developing an android app implementing MVP and clean architecture. I have the following scenario:

- One core module with presenters and view interfaces,...
- One domain module with repositories, data sources,..
- App module with the core implementation (so the Fragment/Activities).

Currently the strings.xml file is in the app module, but I'm thinking whether it should be in a commons module or not. The problem is that, sometimes, the presenter must set the text to the view, so the presenter should need to access to the strings.xml. I've thought in two possible solutions:

1) Create a TextHelper interface on core module that will be implemented on the app module and injected to the presenter, so the presenter will use this helper to get the strings it requires. (This is the solution I have implemented).

2) Move the strings.xml file to a common module so the file can be accessed from core module. But this solution would have a problem: the presenter doesn't have a context.

What do you think? What is the best approach?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think this questions has a lot of answers due to the multiple possibilities to make it right. For my personal opinion, strings are part of the view, so presenter does not have to know about it. Then the view will have methods to show messages with string resurce inside, and the presenter just need to call them.

Comment: You can take a look at this sample project http://github.com/mmirhoseini/marvel and this article https://hackernoon.com/yet-another-mvp-article-part-1-lets-get-to-know-the-project-d3fd553b3e21 to get more familiar with MVP.

Comment: It can happen that part of the business logic is to show the right text to the users, so presenters and usecases/interactors have to handle strings and/or their formatting. This makes possible to make unit-tests that verify if the correct text is emitted, instead of leaving that responsibility to the view and be forced to use slow, flaky instrumentation tests.

Answer (score 2):

If your view has nested `if`/`else`s related to strings, then they should probably be unit-tested. Therefore, that logic should stay in presenters or use-cases, where can be tested more quickly.

Your question is about how to retrieve the actual strings, given that they reside in the "outer layers" of the Clean Architecture scheme, i.e. in the Context object. IMHO your `TextHelper` is the right approach, as it allows to inject a mock when writing unit tests: you're interested in how the strings are *processed*, rather than how the strings actually *look*. I'm trying a very similar approach and calling it `StringsRepository`.

A point of uncertainty is how the the repository API should look like:

1. A single method like `getString(@StringRes int stringResId, Object... formatArgs)` that simply wraps `Context.getString()`: very simple to implement, but will make the presenters depend on your `R.string` class, which in turns requires `strings.xml` to be in the same module as your code under test;
2. One method per string with optional arguments, each one containing the reference to the appropriate string ID. This solution allows for best abstraction, but may become big (both the interface and the implementation...) and many domain classes may depend upon it. Handle with care.
3. Like (2), but with several classes, one per each part of your app. Each class may have a base class similar to (1) but with that method with `protected` visibility.

The best options for your case would be (2) or (3), but your mileage may vary.

Answer (score -2):

You can use `Application` class to get the context any where from the app.

```
public class MVPApplication extends Application {
    private static Context context;

    public static Context getContext() {
        return context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        context = getApplicationContext();
    }
}
```